# create function to pass into dplyr::summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

In my data preparation, I want to create a function for repeated computations into the `summarise` function. So the idea is to create a function like so:

```
my_func <- 
  function(criteria){
  sum(case_when(eval(rlang::parse_expr(criteria)))*100, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

So then, I can use that function to parse different criteria:

```
DT %>% 
  group_by(group_var) %>% 
  summarise(
    # Indicator A:
    ia = my_func(var_x %in% c(1,2,3)~1,TRUE ~ 0),
    # Indicator B:
    ft  = my_func(var_x %in% c(4,5)~1,TRUE ~ 0)
)
```

But, with the above code, I got an error. I really appreciate any idea on how to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO there is no reason to use `rlang::parse_expr`. Instead you could use `...` like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

my_func <- function(...) {
  sum(case_when(...) * 100, na.rm = TRUE)
}

mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise(
    ia = my_func(cyl %in% c(4, 6) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am    ia
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0   700
#> 2     1  1100
```

**EDIT** To pass a column to scale the result instead of the hard-coded 100 you could do:

```r
my_func <- function(..., scale) {
  sum(case_when(...) * {{ scale }}, na.rm = TRUE)
}

mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise(
    ia = my_func(cyl %in% c(4, 6) ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0, scale = mpg)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      am    ia
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     0  145.
#> 2     1  286.
```

Comment: Actually works well. Thank you. Now I have a complementary question. When I tried to change that `100` by a variable of my dataset, I got an error, saying that the variable does not exist. Is there a way to pass that variable into the function? I tried something like `.x`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Sure could you pass another column. See my edit.

Comment: Works just great. Thank you. I'm intrigued by how the first element of the function do not mess up with so many commas. Anyway, I'm happy it works. Thanks!!